# $_SESSION wont load first attempt

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I got some script. And when I input username and pass it opens some fields to fill and to udapte mysql_query..

Here is the problem:

When I fill out the fields, it redirects me on process.php page. And process.php can't recognize the session username, but when I get back and fill it agian and press Submit, it works..

It happends every time (one time) when I open browser..

index.php

```
session_start();
$name= $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['name']= $name;
```

process.php

```
session_start();
$name= $_SESSION['name'];
```

Comment: Nobody can understand.

Comment: It's like admin panel, and form action is process.php

but process.php can't recognize a &_SESSION on first attempt, I have to go back and fill it agian...

Comment: `When I fill out the fields, it redirects me on process.php page.` Sounds like the form submits to `process.php` but your `index.php` is what accepts the `post` and therefore the `$_SESSION['name']=$name` isn't being set due to this

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding what the session is. The session is information stored about a user on the SERVER. When you set a session variable, the server gives your browser a cookie to identify you, and provides that information on request. This information is only valid in each browsing SESSION.

Therefore every time you close all your tabs and open up a new fresh browser and load a page, you have a new CLEAN session.

I believe you are confusing cookies with session.

That being said, make sure if you use cookies, you do not store a users personal information in a cookie, as they are insecure in the fact that they are submitted on every request to the server.

So if you stored in plain text someones password in a cookie, someone could listen in on your conversation with the server (if you were on an unsecured wifi for instance), and steal their password.

Comment: Hm..

Index.php contains:

form with username and password... action=""

when I fill the fields it opens second form below with action=process.php"

When I fill second form... it redirects me on process.php... and there is $_SESSION['name'] empty..

If I go back on index.php and fill the form agian.. $_SESSION['name'] is not empty and it works...

Comment: For a first, you're opening yourself up to sql injection with your $ime, I could forge the post request and pass whatever information I want directly to your sql request. And perform malicious actions.

Comment: A POST is a type of http request, you are performing a post from index.php to index.php on line 24 in index.php where you set `action=""`. Therefore $_SESSION["ime"] is only ever set when you submit that form. also you start and close your form in bad places, you should do something like this `<form><table></table></form>` not `<table><tr><td><form></td></tr><tr><td></form></td></tr></table>`